# Probability of selecting a card with a rank higher than another card.

Tags: probability, statistics

Sara and Pedros each have a standard deck of cards. Independently, each of them selects a card uniformly at random from their respective decks. What is the probability that the rank of Sara’s card is strictly higher than the rank of Petros’s card?

My thinking is that if Petros picks a 2, then there are 12 ranks (48 cards) that would ensure $x>y$. The probability for this scenario is $\frac{4}{52} \times \frac{48}{52}$.

continuing like this, we have $\frac{4}{52} \times (\frac{48}{52} + \frac{44}{52}... + \frac{4}{52}) = \frac{312*4}{52^2} = \frac{1248}{2704}$.

But am i correct in multiplying each scenario by $\frac{4}{52}$? Or would I just add each favorable outcome (48+44....+4) and divide this by $52^2$?

I would really appreciate some guidance on this!

Comment: It may be easier to find prob [rank sara=rank pedros], then subtract from 1 and divide by 2.

Comment: hm this makes sense but it gives me 16/34, which is different from both the methods i originally tried.

Comment: @user2661923 They are drawing from separate decks.

Comment: yes.....drawing from separate decks. So it would be 6/13? Obviously this method is a lot simpler but it looks like my approach works too?

Comment: @cdub You made error trying my method. prob(sara=pedro)=1/13 so my method gives (1-1/13)/2=6/13.

Comment: @DanielMathias Nice catch, my mistake.  I therefore deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to multiply by $\frac4{52}$. It is however advantageous to reduce the final fraction:
$$
\frac{4}{52} \times \left(\frac{48}{52} + \frac{44}{52}... + \frac{4}{52}\right) =\frac6{13}.
$$
This coincides with the result which can be obtained by the simpler method proposed in the comments.